# Finding ip address using python's socket module

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

When I run the following command to get the host ip:

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

I am getting the following error on MAC terminal:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

`socket.gethostname()` does return the correct hostname.

Comment: have you tried to pass `socket.gethostname().strip()` ?

Comment: yes I tried that but it didn't help

Comment: if you try to `ping` (from command line) the host that `socket.gethostname()` returns, does it say `unknown host`?

Comment: that's right. it does say unknown host! any idea what would cause that? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open **as root** `/etc/hosts` file, and add a line like the following

```
# IP ADDR      HOSTNAME
192.168.1.1    your_desired_hostname
```

and the name should resolve.

Obviously substitute `192.168.1.1` with your ip address.