# Using SSHTunnel Correctly

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel, pymysql

I'm trying to use `pymysql` and `sshtunnel` in python2.7 to tunnel my connection so that I can connect to a mysql instance that is only accessible via a bastion server. The bastion server has a hostname of `BASTIONIP` and that server can connection to `MYSQLHOST` with no problem. However, python can't seem to connect via the tunnel. Below is my code:

```
    with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (BASTIONIP, 22),
            ssh_username='dataengineer',
            ssh_pkey="/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa",
            remote_bind_address=(MYSQLHOST, 3306),
            local_bind_address=(MYSQLHOST, 3306)
    ) as tunnel:
        self.DB = {'con': pymysql.connect(host=MYSQLHOST,
                                          user=USERNAME,
                                          passwd=PASSWORD,
                                          db=DBNAME,
                                          port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                          charset='utf8',
                                          autocommit=True)}
        self.DB['cursor'] = self.DB['con'].cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

However, when I try to connect I get the following error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1378, in _get_local_interfaces
    local_if = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[-1]
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `local_bind_address` is on your computer not on the mysql server, try setting it to localhost: `local_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)` or `local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)`

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try changing the `local_bind_address` to either `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`. Note that this is being run within a django app that runs on `0.0.0.0:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons I could figure out after some googling are mentioned below:

1. Not Sure, it was caused by _get_local_interfaces trying to resolve the local hostname and failing (probably just a bad /etc/hosts file or something)

Try to open as root `/etc/hosts` file, and add a line like the following

```
# IP ADDR      HOSTNAME
192.168.1.1    your_desired_hostname
```

and the name should resolve.
update `192.168.1.1` with your ip address.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332065/finding-ip-address-using-pythons-socket-module)

2. Another Resolution:
   Replace :

`local_if = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[-1]`

with

```
  try:
    local_if = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[-1]
except:
    local_if = []
```

[Here](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/issues/56)

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm.

```
In [1]: from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
   ...:     ...: 
   ...:     ...: with SSHTunnelForwarder(
   ...:     ...:     ('xx.xx.xx.xx', 22),
   ...:     ...:     ssh_username='deploy',
   ...:     ...:     ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/id_rsa',
   ...:     ...:     remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
   ...:     ...:     local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 3307)
   ...:     ...: ) as tunnel:
   ...:     ...:     print('pass')
   ...: 
   ...:     
pass
```